# nslookup/dig not appending domain suffix for SRV searches

Tags: ubuntu, dns, dig, nslookup

I am trying to figure out why doing a SRV record search on Ubuntu will not work without specifically including the FQDN on the end of the address.  I have the domain name listed in my resolv.conf within the `search` parameter.  The search works on Windows using nslookup without appending the FQDN though.  I've been unable to find anything on the various forums.  The query just returns NXDOMAIN unless I put the FQDN.

Answer (score 0):

From the `dig` man page...

> +[no]search Use [do not use] the search list defined by the searchlist or domain directive in resolv.conf (if any). The search list is not
> used by default.

which means it does not happen by default. So, `dig +search -t srv <host>`. It works here against other types, I just don't have a `srv` to test with.

`nslookup` seems a bit, iffy...

Comment: Yup, I tried `+search` but it doesn't make `dig` work either.

Comment: Well, it works here. Does it work with other types? Perhaps you have an error in `/etc/resolv.conf`.

Comment: Yes, it works with other types.  Normally, I don't specify the query type and those work as I'd expect appending the various suffixes in the list until a match is found.  But with an SRV record it doesn't work.  I also tried appending a . (period) to the end of the SRV lookup as the documentation states to end with a period if it is in a domain other than the current domain.  Sadly that fails as well.